# Unable to create secrets in Azure Key Vault if using Azure role-based access control

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-keyvault, rbac

I'm really new to Azure but trying to learn - so apologies if this is a daft question. I've started the free trial (which gives me some credit to start with), and I'm trying to create a key vault. If I specify "Vault access policy" under access policies, it works great and I'm able to create secrets. I'd like to use "Azure role-based access control" though instead. If I create a key vault using Azure role-based access control, I get a message when trying to create a new secret which says "The operation is not allowed by RBAC. If role assignments were recently changed, please wait several minutes for role assignments to become effective." I am logged into Azure as the Service Administrator, so I don't think it's a permissions issue. I have left it overnight, and it still displays the message, so I don't think it's a matter of not waiting long enough for role assignments to become effective. I have tried creating the key vault in different regions and get the same results. Note that this is happening when I create a key vault using Azure role-based access control from scratch (i.e. I am not changing it from one to the other or anything like that.) Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for any help
Andrew

Comment: Please be concise in your problem statement.

Comment: Thanks, this matches the problem I am encountering exactly.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If you are creating the Key vault with RBAC role from scratch then Please assign **`Key vault Administrator`** to your name for creating/ managing the secrets, certificates and keys.

Steps:

1. Go to your Key vault after its created and then click on Access
   Control (IAM):

   [image]
2. Then click on Add Role assignment and then add Key vault
   Administrator Role to your name:

   [image]

   [image]
3. After you review and assign the role , you will be successfully able
   to create/manage the objects present inside the Key vault.

Comment: Thanks both for your help! I was able to create keys once I'd granted myself the Key Vault Administrator Role (which I am surprised I had to do given that I am the Service Administrator.)

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and it fixed it for me too. I did not require this role in another Azure environment I develop on, so this came as a bit of a surprise. But I think the resource had been created differently in that environment, which is why it had not been an issue for me there.

Comment: Any reason why access won't work if granting to a group? Granting to an user works ok.

Answer (score 4):

If you provide access to Key Vault keys, certificates, and secrets with an Azure role-based access control, then you need to use a specific built-in role or a custom one with allowed operations on the Data plane.

You have the list of those aforementioned built-in roles in the [official documentation for Key Vault RBAC permission model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli#azure-built-in-roles-for-key-vault-data-plane-operations).

The role you have assigned most probably do not have access to Key Vault Data plane. You can find the whole list of operation providers at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftkeyvault). See that there is a distinction between `Actions` which are actions at infrastructure level vs `DataActions` which are actions at the data level, what is inside your Key Vault. Most of roles do not have access to this.

Comment: Thanks for this! You've now given me some extra work to do to understand the difference between actions and dataActions :)